# Dates showing up as numbers

Tags: excel

I'm new to using excel and I just created a workbook wondering why the dates I'm putting in are being changed to numbers

Examples that I can include are the following:
`44856` is what’s showing up instead of `10/22/22` and `45164` is showing up instead of `08/26/23`

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: That's how Excel represents dates. Whole numbers are the date part and the fractions are the time. That way you can do formulas involving dates `=A1+1` is then next day if `a1` is a date.

Comment: I think I get that. The whole numbers showing up are the dates converted but that’s not what I’m looking for. Instead of dates, it shows up as those numbers even if the format is set to dates. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated my question as well because I think I got it the other way around. Sorry, groggy already.

Comment: How exactly are you imputing your new date values? Which regional setting is currently applied in your Windows/Excel workbook? Depending on this Excel tries to be "helpful" in deciding whether a new value "looks" like a date or a number. And sometimes Excel guesses wrongly. By setting the number format for a column you can strongly influence this behaviour.

Comment: @David - Then you're entering numbers as text and they can't be formatted as dates. Try doing `=VALUE(A1)` and see if you can format that.

Comment: Apologies if I have not gotten back to my question. Surprisingly enough, when I accessed the file the next morning everything works! I mean, I had to change the format of the numbers again but it wasn’t working the day before. I’m happy that everything’s working now. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

It means the number format was applied to cells. Select any of those cells and press 'Ctrl+1' to call 'Format cells' dialog. Apply any data/time format you like.

Initially a cell has no format, and Excel tries to interpret the entered value as the data/time, then as the number, then the value will be assumed as the text. An appropriate format will be assigned to the cell.

A format gotten this way or gotten from other cell while entering formula is "automatic" and not persistent. Excel will follow the rule above while entering a new value.

A format assigned manually by 'Format cells' is persistent. You need to clear or change such format manually as well as it was assigned. Since a cell is hard formatted the newly entered value will be interpreted and displayed in this format, if possible, not following the default rule.